# Filling Table from Numbers using macros

Tags: tables, macros

I want to replace 3,0.35,0.35,17, 2 and 2, with inputs from a data imported from Numbers. Is there a way to do that. The table from Numbers would look like this:

```
pone  xone    total
3      0.35    0.35
10     1       1 
17     2       2
```

And this is how I currently hard-code the numbers

```
\def\pone{3}
\def\xone{0.35}
\def\total{0.35}




\def\TPone{17}
\def\TMone{2}
\def\T{2}

\begin{table}[h]
        \begin{center}
        \scriptsize
        \label{1}
        \scriptsize
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
        
             \begin{tabular}{|m{0.7\textwidth}|  % <-- use 'm', not 'p', col. type
                         w{c}{0.07 \textwidth}|  
                         w{c}{0.07 \textwidth}|  
                         w{c}{0.07 \textwidth}|                       
                       }
                          
                                      \hline   \hline
            \rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
            Course Learning Outcomes (CLO)$^\star$ & Question  & Points& Mark\\ \hline
            \hline 
\CLOone & 1& \pone /\TPone & \xone /\TMone \\ \hline                      
 \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{Total} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\total/\T } \\ \hline    \hline        
        \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
        \vspace{-0.5em}
 \scriptsize{\underline{$^\star$ Linkages to Program Outcomes and Concentration Outcomes are provided in the Syllabus. } }  
\end{table}
  \normalsize
 
 Marking scheme :
 \begin{itemize}
 \item Each question/part/subpart has an assigned $n$ point value, where
 \begin{itemize}
 \item a point is lost for each mistake,
 \item $n$ points are lost for $n$ number of mistakes or more.
 \end{itemize}
 \item The final mark score equals the mark allocated for the question scaled by the points earned divided by the question point value.
 \end{itemize}
 


\begin{center}
\rule{.7\textwidth}{1pt}\\
\footnotesize{If you have mistakes please check the key answer to know your mistakes}\\
\footnotesize Instructor: \underline{\textbf{\normalfont\calligra Dr. Diana Dawoud}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When you say "imported from Numbers" do you mean copy pasted to your editor or as a file. Assuming Numbers can save as CSV there are plenty of CSV to table packages around, `pgfplotstable`, `csvsimple` or `datatool`, to name three of the more popular ones.

Comment: If you just want to cut and paste cells from Numbers, in TeXShop you can do that from the Macros menu (Paste Spreadsheet Cells).